# How to solve Pylearn2 installation error?

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, pylearn2

I got this error when trying to install Pylearn2 software.
[import error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF5Kc.png) 
I follow the download & installation instruction at their website http://deeplearning.net/software/pylearn2/. I have already install setuptools module using anaconda.
[setup tools module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzAXt.png).
How do I solve this?

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 with python 2.7